# UITableView cell not displaying text as expected

Tags: uitableview

I have a table view that seems to be working, but it's not displaying text in the cell as expected. In other words when I load the tableView it shows only blank cells, whereas I would expect one cell to display a the text requested in the code below.

Is there anything wrong with my code below?

NOTE: I'm only implementing cellForRowAtIndexPath as my tableView is a subclass of Stanford's `CoreDataTableViewController`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"a_cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"cell is nil");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    //Page is a managed object entity with a name attribute.
    Page *page = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //The log below returns the expected string for the name value.
    NSLog(@"page.name %@", page.name);
    cell.textLabel.text = @"page.name";

    return cell;
}
```

There is only one object or "Page" as of now, so I would expect only one cell in the tableView (the top) to display text. In fact all ate blank.

When I log the indexPath using:

```
NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath %@", indexPath);
```

I get the following printed once:

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath <NSIndexPath 0x836f1d0> 2 indexes [0, 0]
```

Is that the first cell?

Curiously when I try to color the cell like below the cell remains white also:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Below is the header for the tableViewController (mine, not Stanford's). Note the context property, that is so I could pass the coreData managedObjectContext in to perform the fetch I needed.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CoreDataTableViewController.h"

@interface CDST02TableViewController : CoreDataTableViewController


@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *context;


@end
```

Comment: Please post the rest of your UITableViewCell Delegate methods

Comment: @ing0 I think there are no others, as I am using Stanford's CoreDataTableViewController. My TableViewController is a subclass of that, so I'm only implementing cellForRowAtIndexPath. The rest is the code from CDTVC.

Comment: There is possibly something wrong with the `Page` object. Is this a `NSObject`? Does it log `page.name` correctly?

Comment: @ing0 Yes the name is "currentPage" and it logs correctly.

Comment: Either you have a typo in the question or I just answered it... 8)

Comment: I'm assuming `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning `[fetchedResultsController count]`. You are trying to log the indexPath to a string (%@). Try logging like this: `NSLog(@"indexPath section: %i, row: %i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);` The 0,0 you see is section 0, row 0.

Comment: Your question says **"UITableView cell not loading"** but in description you describe another problem. Please make it unanimous.

Comment: @ing0 yes, that returned: indexPath section: 0, row: 0. As expected

Comment: Does it ever log "cell is nil"?

Comment: Can you post the header file for your tableViewController?

Comment: You might have missed delegates and datasource for that CoreDataTableViewController, kindly check that too??

Comment: @Bala it looks like the datasource is working fine, and the logging he's explained suggests the delegates are fine too.

Comment: @ing0 yes, and it's not currently nil when I log it.

Comment: @Mrwolfy I can only suggest you try using `UITableView` rather than `CoreDataTableViewController` to see if that's the problem.

Comment: @ing0 thanks. I added the header for you...

Comment: `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
int noOfRows = [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
NSLog@"noOfRows = %d",noOfRows;
    return noOfRows;
}` log this please..

Comment: @Bala, as I said above, it looks like that is setup fine. cellForRowAtIndexPath is only being called once which is expected as there is only one element in his managed object.

Comment: i did a sample project with using the same [CoreDataTableViewController](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/CoreDataTableViewController_0.zip) and its working very fine. if you are interested i can send you that sample

Comment: @ing0 I found the solution. I have to apologize. The first cell was hidden by an interface element I had added, so in fact there was no issue. Thanks for your help! Please add an answer saying "check if any interface element is hiding the first row". I will accept the first one who does so, as I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @Bala I found the solution. I have to apologize. The first cell was hidden by an interface element I had added, so in fact there was no issue. Thanks for your help! Please add an answer saying "check if any interface element is hiding the first row". I will accept the first one who does so, as I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @Mrwolfy It would be even better, if you answer that yourself.

Comment: @Bala, thanks it's fine, but then you don't get any points. but cheers anyway.

Comment: @Mrwolfy you can answer yourself, but I have written it anyway. Glad you sorted it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"page.name";
```

To:

```
cell.textLabel.text = page.name;
```

If that doesn't work, check if any interface element is hiding the first row ;)

Comment: You are right! But that is just a typo in this post, sorry, thanks for catching.